# get paramterized type java reflection

Tags: java, reflection

Is there anyway to get the inner type parameter of a field using reflection

For Ex:

```
public final class Main
{
        class A
        {
                public int aX;
                public String aS;
        }

        class B
        {
                public Set<A> bSet;
        }
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
                Class clazz = B.class.getField("bSet").getType();
        }
};
```

Using the above I can only get "Set" is there anyway I could get A as well ? 
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reflection can indeed deliver full parameterized types for fields (and classes, etc). It's only *objects* that have their types erased at runtime.

Call `getGenericType` instead of `getType` and start reading javadoc.

Comment: Thanks :) .. I did go through the docs wonder how i how missed that.